# Break the sentence into words using a regular expression preg_split

Tags: php, regex

I get the input string but with completely understandable and predictable) it has any text in any language (English, Russian, Japanese, Arabic ...) We need to split a string of words and numbers but say Japanese text split by symbols and remove symbols

I work in PHP using preg_split

code:

```
$arr = preg_split("/[^\p{L}\p{N}]/u", $text, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

Log in $text:

```
攻壳机动队 ARISE 2 - [BCXA-0740]
```

Gate array $arr:

```
攻
壳
机
动
队
ARISE
2
BCXA
0740
```

Some information http://www.localizingjapan.com/blog/2012/01/20/regular-expressions-for-japanese-text/

Comment: check on this link http://www.php.net/mbstring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your regex, you might try:

```
\B(?=\p{Han})|\W
```

Assuming all of your Japanese script is Kanji.  If there might be others in your real data, just add it to the look-ahead using alternation

Comment: and how it will look in the setup function `preg_split`?

Comment: I do not understand how to enter your code in the


`preg_split("/[^\B(?=\p{Han})|\W\p{N}]/u", $text, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);`

it's not working

Comment: You enter the regex into the command using the same method as you would for any other regex. I assume you know how to do that since you provided code that wasn't working as you wished. I also see you have modified what I provided.  I don't understand your modifications (they don't seem to even produce a valid regex), but I would suggest you start with the same regex I provided, and only modify it after you see what it does. '/\B(?=\p{Han})|\W/u'